# How to push a new viewController in a tableview which is a inserted view of a navigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, navigation, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a HomeViewController.m in which I push SpecificViewController by `self.navigationController`,

```
 SpecificViewController *specificViewController= [[SpecificViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpecificViewController" bundle:nil];  
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:specificViewController animated:YES];
```

And in SpecificViewController.m I insert a subview

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view insertSubview:firstViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

And in FirstViewController.m, there is a tableview. The question is how can I push a new ViewController by navigationController, I have try below, but it does not work.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
 DetailTableViewController *detail = 
 [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
 [detail release];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I still tried a new UINavigationController,

```
UINavigationController *NEWnavigationController;
NEWnavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];                
[NEWnavigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

but it still did not work. Could you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with your approach.

First, is SpecificViewController the first view controller you load? If yes, then you do not push this view controller rather you set it as the root view controller in your application delegate as shown below

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SpecificViewController alloc] init];
```

This will ensure that your Navigation controller is setup and the first view controller that appears is the SpecificViewController

Secondly, you dont insert a view controller as a subview. If you are trying to load a second view controller then you push that onto your navigation controller stack. You can do that from SpecificViewController as shown below

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController =[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];
```